# Manipulating pixel color in HTML canvas to another color but with the same shade

Tags: javascript, colors, html5-canvas

I've got a function that allows me to draw an image on a temporarily invisible canvas to manipulate the colors and change everything that isn't solid black to the specific color, however, keeping the original white "shade".

However, when trying to perform that action, the color is much darker than it should be.

I've written the function to replace the color with the new color minus the old color which has been subtracted with 255.

```
    for(var i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i+=4) {
      if((imageData.data[i] != 0 &&
          imageData.data[i + 1] != 0 &&
          imageData.data[i + 2] != 0)) {

        imageData.data[i] = newColor.r - (255 - imageData.data[i]);
        imageData.data[i + 1] = newColor.g - (255 - imageData.data[i + 1]);
        imageData.data[i + 2] = newColor.b - (255 - imageData.data[i + 2]);

        if(imageData.data[i] > 255)
          imageData.data[i] = 255;

        if(imageData.data[i + 1] > 255)
          imageData.data[i + 1] = 255;

        if(imageData.data[i + 2] > 255)
          imageData.data[i + 2] = 255;
      }
    }
```

Given the new color to be #44698B (r:68, g: 105, b:139), the outcome for the slightly greyer white #999 (153, 153, 153) part came out as #000325 (0, 3, 36) whereas it should've been #2F4860 (47, 72, 96).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting RGB values while retaining shade is difficult. I would recommend switching to HSL. Here's a link on the topic: https://css-tricks.com/hsl-hsla-is-great-for-programmatic-color-control/

Comment: Thank you. After 2 hours of constant headaches, I've finally gotten what I needed. The new constructor goes as... the lightness is calculated by taking the new color's lightness, diving it by a whole, multiplying the old lightness with that multiplier, giving the new lightness for the new color based on the old one `(oldColorLightness * (oldColorLightness / 1.0))`.